# Having problem in puting JavaScript Menu into Asp.Net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, html, .net-3.5

Before I post my problem here, please be noted that i would really like to leave javascript and css for that menu as it is.

Now to my problem.
I have a menu in JavaScript that I am having a problem putting into asp.net page, I am having problem to produce the proper html to be more correct.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

the menu in html looks like:

```
        <!-- HOME -->
        <div class="menu_item" onmouseover="hide_all_panels();">
            <a href="/default.aspx">Home</a>
        </div>


        <!-- ABOUT SITE -->
        <div id="trigger1" onmouseover="show_panel('0');">
            <div class="menu_item">

                <a href="/about_us.aspx">About Us</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden_div">
                <!-- ABOUT WEB SITE POPOUT -->
                <div class="menu" id="popout1">
                    <div class="menu_item">
                        <a href="/frequently_asked_questions.aspx">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu_item">
                        <a href="/our_team.aspx">Our Team</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu_item">
                        <a href="/our_board.aspx">The Board</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

```
            <a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
        </div>


        <!-- CONTACT US -->
        <div class="menu_item" onmouseover="hide_all_panels();">
            <a href="/contact.aspx">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
```

as you can see, the **divs** are not symmetric for single menu that has not children I have simply *link wraped into div*, but for the menu with childrens I have a menu with *one trigger div and 2 more somewhat main divs inside it.*

I tryed to put something like that for this menu on asp.net side (don't put atentions to link namings now, they are not important):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_Menu" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_Menu_DataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_MainSubmenuDiv" runat="server" Visible="false" Enabled="false">
                        <div id="trigger<%= index %>" onmouseover="show_panel('<%= index %>');">
                    </asp:Panel>

                    <div class="menu_item" onmouseover="hide_all_panels();">
                        <a href="/default.aspx"><%# Eval("menu_name") %></a>
                    </div>

                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_Id" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("menu_id") %>' />
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_SubMenu" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <div class="menu" id="popout<%= index %>">
                               <div class="menu_item">
                                   <a href="/about_us.aspx"><%# Eval("menu_name") %></a>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>

                    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_MainSubmenuClose" runat="server" Visible="false" Enabled="false">
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

and the code behind is very simple and there is nothing special, all i do is just bind second repeater that inside first repeater and make panels visible or invisible:

```
 protected void rpt_Menu_DataBound(object obj, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        int parent_id = Int32.Parse(((HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdn_Id")).Value.ToString());
        using (SamaraDataContext mycity = new SamaraDataContext())
        {
            var subMenu = from sm in mycity.tbl_menus
                          where (sm.menu_parent == parent_id)
                          select new
                          {
                              menu_id = sm.menu_id,
                              menu_name = sm.menu_name
                          };

            int count = 0;
            foreach (var item in subMenu)
            {
                count++;
            }

            if (count > 0)
            {
                ((Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnl_MainSubmenuDiv")).Visible = true;
                ((Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnl_MainSubmenuClose")).Visible = true;
                ((Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rpt_SubMenu")).DataSource = subMenu.ToList();
                ((Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rpt_SubMenu")).DataBind();
                this.index++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However my problems is that panels produce div's even if they are hidden, which breaks out all the html structure.

I would really dislike to put the divs formating inside the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To supplement blesh's answer, use the `PlaceHolder` control instead of `Panel`. Placeholders do not render HTML surrounding the contents.

Answer (score 2):

Well for one thing this section here:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_MainSubmenuClose" runat="server" Visible="false" Enabled="false">
  </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Will render invalid HTML if Visible is set to true, thus potentially screwing up your JavaScript and CSS interactions.

That will come out like so:

```
<div id="something_something_pnl_MainSubmenuClose">
  </div>
</div>
```

as Panel controls render a  around whatever they enclose. So figure a way around that, and you'll likely solve your problem.

Comment: You point is very right, panels are the one responsible for breaking my html structure..., but i seems to not be able to find solution to replace them, anything else i put i need to render html inside a code behind. Which i would like not to do. And even then, anything else i replace those panel, will still produce something on html side, some sort of tag...